Composable is not refreshing on LiveData updates
I'm working in a notification tracker as a personal project to learn Kotlin. For it, I want to make a simple list of all the notifications that comes to the phone. However, even though I create a View Model which is updating the list of received notifications, it doesn't affect the UI, which has the View Model as a list extracting the notifications as a list using observeAsState. Here is the code for everything
MainActivity.kt
package com.tomasdfen.banknotificationtracker

import android.Manifest
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.tomasdfen.banknotificationtracker.ui.theme.BankNotificationTrackerTheme
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.provider.Settings
import android.text.TextUtils
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat

private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
private const val REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATIONS = 1001
private var counter = 0

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: NotificationViewModel by viewModels()

    private fun isNotificationServiceEnabled(): Boolean {
        val pkgName = packageName
        val flat: String = Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners") ?: return false
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(flat)) {
            val names = flat.split(":".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            for (name in names) {
                val cn = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(name)
                if (cn != null && TextUtils.equals(pkgName, cn.packageName)) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity created.")

        if (!isNotificationServiceEnabled()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Notification listener service is not enabled.")
            val intent = Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS")
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.w(TAG, "POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission not granted. Requesting permission.")
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS), REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            BankNotificationTrackerTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    NotificationList(
                        viewModel = viewModel,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NotificationList(viewModel: NotificationViewModel, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val notifications by viewModel.notifications.observeAsState(emptyList())
    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(notifications) {
        // This ensures the UI reacts when notifications list changes
        Log.d("NotificationList", "Notification list has changed!")
    }

    // Debugging log for notification count
    Log.d("NotificationList", "Notifications size: ${notifications.size}")

    Column(modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        Button(onClick = { sendTestNotification(context) }) {
            Text(text = "Send Test Notification")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        LazyColumn {
            items(notifications) { notification ->
                val title = notification.notification.extras.getString("android.title", "Sin título")
                Text(text = title)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}

// Define the sendNotification method
fun sendTestNotification(context: Context) {
    val notificationId = 1001
    val channelId = "test_channel"

    // Create a notification channel (required for Android O and later)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = "Test Channel"
        val descriptionText = "Channel for test notifications"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }

        // Use NotificationManager (not NotificationManagerCompat) to create the channel
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    // Create an intent to launch the app when the notification is clicked
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    // Build the notification
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground) // Replace with your app's icon
        .setContentTitle("Test Notification $counter")
        .setContentText("This is a test notification.")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)

    counter += 1

    // Use NotificationManagerCompat to show the notification
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(notificationId, builder.build())

    Log.d("MainActivity", "Test notification sent.")
}


NotificationViewModel.kt
package com.tomasdfen.banknotificationtracker

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import android.util.Log
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification

private const val TAG = "NotificationViewModel"


class NotificationViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _notifications = MutableLiveData<List<StatusBarNotification>>()
    val notifications: LiveData<List<StatusBarNotification>> = _notifications


    fun addNotification(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        val currentList = _notifications.value.orEmpty().toMutableList()
        currentList.add(sbn)
        _notifications.value = currentList  // This triggers a recomposition in the UI
        val title = sbn.notification.extras.getString("android.title", "Sin título")

        Log.d(TAG, "Notifications: ${notifications} (title='$title')")
    }

    fun removeNotification(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        val currentList = _notifications.value.orEmpty().toMutableList()
        currentList.remove(sbn)
        _notifications.value = currentList  // This triggers a recomposition in the UI
    }
}

NotificationListener.kt
package com.tomasdfen.banknotificationtracker

import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

private const val TAG = "NotificationListener"

class NotificationListenerService : NotificationListenerService() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: NotificationViewModel

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application).create(NotificationViewModel::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, "NotificationListenerService created.")
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification posted: ${sbn.notification.extras?.getString("android.title")}")
        viewModel.addNotification(sbn)
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification removed: ${sbn.notification.extras.getString("android.title", "Sin título")}, Package: ${sbn.packageName}")
        viewModel.removeNotification(sbn)
    }
}

I've already tried logging all the data in every method and logging when the NotificationList composable loads, which only does on the app startup
